# How to transform &#xxx; characters to their normal representation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xslt

I am getting unwated `&#xxx;` characters that I'd like to convert back to the original.

Let's perform a simple XSL transform that does nothing (output = input) **with Russian characters**:

`input.xml` is:

```
<root>Здраве</root>
```

`transform.xsl` is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my python code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse("input.xml")
xslt = ET.parse("transform.xsl")
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

The output is:

```
b'<root>&#1047;&#1076;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1077;</root>\n'
```

Demo: https://repl.it/join/lktibwya-vincentandrieu

My problem is I need to save this to a file that reads `Здраве`, not `&#1047;&#1076;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1077;`

How can I transform the special chars into their normal representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the html module:

```
html.unescape('<root>&#1047;&#1076;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1077;</root>\n')

'<root>Здраве</root>\n'
```

If you are receiving bytes, you would need to convert them to a string first:

```
b = b'<root>&#1047;&#1076;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1077;</root>\n'

html.unescape(b.decode('utf-8'))

'<root>Здраве</root>\n'
```

You may also try to use `encoding='unicode'` in the call to ET.tostring.  It should return a Python string directly since Python uses unicode internally for strings:

```
 print(ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: `encoding='unicode'` is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically &#1088 here `1088` is Unicode code-point. In python, you can convert a Unicode code point to actual representation by `chr(integer value of Unicode code point)`.

Also the leading `b'<root...` means it is `binary`. So we need to use `.decode()` to convert it to `string`.

Finally, we can use `regular expression` to get the Unicode code point by-
`&#(\d{4});`
`&#` : will match starting with `&#`
`(` `)` : capturing a group
`\d{4}` : selecting digits of length 4
`;` : end with `;`

```py
import re

a = b'<root>&#1047;&#1076;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1077;</root>\n'
''.join([chr(int(i)) for i in re.findall(r'&#(\d{4});', a.decode())])
```

```
Здраве
```